# GA event not getting fired for broken images loaded from css file

Tags: javascript, css, google-analytics

I have below GA code in my javascript. window.addEventListener method captures any broken link or images which result in 404 and fires _gaq.push method.
Below code is working fine for all broken links / images but its not firing _gaq call if broken *image is from css file*. 
I have checked in browser my js file is getting loaded before my css file.
below is the sequence of files getting loaded-

- -common.js
- -common.css
- -xyz
- -xyz
- -ga.js : initiator is common.js but its loaded after common.css
- broken_image.gif: causing 404 - not getting detected.

Below is my GA code-

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push([ '_setAccount', 'UA-34xxxxx-1' ]);
_gaq.push([ '_trackPageview' ]);

(function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script');
    ga.type = 'text/javascript';
    ga.async = true;
    ga.src = 'https://ssl.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();

window.addEventListener('error', function(e) {
    _gaq.push([ '_trackEvent', '404 myapp', 'Missing Element',
            e.target && e.target.src ? e.target.src : '', 1 ]);

}, true);
```

url call which is failing-

```
.myTool {
    background: url("../images/common/my-tool.jpg") no-repeat 0 0;
}
```

Comment: Google analytics is loading asynchronously. Are you sure it's loaded before your stylesheet has loaded?

Comment: Also, can you not just track the 404s through webmaster tools?

Comment: ga.js is getting loaded before the call to broken image results in 404

Comment: also, I believe the url is invoked by jsp only when image is supposed to be rendered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The onerror event requires/supports only certain html tags: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onerror.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onerror_media.asp

and occurs from HTML5 Server-Sent Events.

So since the "in CSS" dowloadables don't contain any of the above mentioned the onerror event is never fired

Comment: so, it means there is no way for GA to capture broken-images which are downloaded by css ?

Comment: doesn't appear possible to capture that 404 in the DOM

Comment: you are right!! I tried all possibilities, none worked. I think good solution will be to have a common 404 error page in web application and filtering in GA UI for 404 'page-title' and locating the 'full-referer'.